# Have Word Apply Numbering to Existing Outlined Document

Tags: microsoft-word

I've got an existing document that has its heading styles set up correctly (looking at the outline view in the Navigation pane shows the correct layout)--I'd like to add numbering to it. Is there a way to do this retroactively?

Existing text:

```
Heading 1 Text
Heading 2 Text
Heading 1 Text
Heading 2 Text
Heading 3 Text
```

Desired text:

```
1. Heading 1 Text
1.1 Heading 2 Text
2. Heading 1 Text
2.1 Heading 2 Text
2.1.1 Heading 3 Text
```

Thanks!